# IIS and CLR, how do they talk?

Tags: iis, clr

I don't understand and cannot find any article explaining how **IIS** is talking to **CLR** (if it does). I just want to know what happens in between the request and code execution. Any help or links appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIS does not communicate directly with the CLR.

Instead, IIS defines handlers, modules, and filters.  For instance, the handler mapping for *.aspx is the IsapiModule.  Further, there are ISAPI filters added in IIS for handling ASP.Net calls.

[ISAPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Server_Application_Programming_Interface) is the "glue" between IIS and code that handles the requests.  That code may be CLR code.